# Finding outliers in multiple dimensions

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, algorithms, data, outlier

I'm working on a dataset which isn't normally distributed. The dataset contains three dimensions like cost, discount and profit.

I'm trying to find possible outliers in all these dimensions. I used Z-score to detect outliers in single dimension to find which high cost is causing outliers.

As a next step I tried to find outliers with high cost and high profit and low discount.

I came up with a formula of :

```
Zscore(cost) + Zscore(profit) - Zscore(discount)
```

negative sign because I want to find outliers with low discount.

Is this approach meaningful to do? or is there any further proven way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the [Mahalanobis Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)? It's can be thought of as the magnitude of a multi-dimensional Z-score.

The way I prefer to view the the Mahalanobis Distance is as the square root of the exponent of the [Multivariate Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). This is similar to the Z-score, which is the exponent of the univarate normal distribution before the square is applied. A big difference between these two is the Z-score is signed, while the Mahalanobis Distance is unsigned, which doesn't matter for finding outliers anyway.

I understand you don't have normally distributed data, but sometimes pretending your data is normally distributed can have good results, so using the Mahalanobis Distance can be worth investigating.

Comment: sounds interesting could you please elaborate on this

Comment: I added a bit more, explanation, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because  your   data is   normal distributed ( gaussian) you could  easy  try to implement   in your desired    language  this   alghoritm  from  coursera  mooc :
https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/91

Comment: but the question said the data is **not** normal?

Comment: Yeah  I notticed that now , sorry ,  I have not  read the  didn't

Answer (score 0):

Using Z-score can be ok if you're sure about what you're looking for. It can also be just a way to transform your data before using some ML on it. Be aware that Z-score applies to normally distributed data (which you say is not the case). Be also aware that looking for outliers in 3 dimensions is not as simple as looking 3 times for outliers in 1 dimension. You should plot your data in 3D, and try to find where might be the outliers.

Otherwise, one-class SVMs are pretty good at anomaly/outliers detection. Take a look at the introduction [here](http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/). Also, any clustering algorithm might be helpful to get a better insight. [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN), for example, helps you to find clusters based on the density of the data.